# How do you specify a universal iOS application when building through CMake?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, cmake

When I build my app for iOS using cmake it only outputs an iPhone app, not a universal app, which my source is written for. Looking through the cmake documentation, I don't see any mention of how to specify that I want to build a universal or iPad only application. How do you specify a universal iOS application when building through CMake?

Answer (score 6):

```
add_executable(foo ...)
set_target_properties(
    foo PROPERTIES XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY "1,2"
)
```

Answer (score -1):

set_property (TARGET ${MYTARGET} PROPERTY XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY "iPhone/iPad")